# How to access `startCursor` (relay pagination) of the last request (requested page) when using GraphCache in URQL?

Tags: vue.js, pagination, urql, urql-graphcache

My stack is **VueJS** + **Urql** + **Graphcache**.

When using **Graphcache** with relay pagination my query result gets automatically merged which is nice but `pageInfo.startCursor` remains the same as the `pageInfo.startCursor` of the first fetched page.
**Is there a way to access the `pageInfo.startCursor` of the last fetched page?**

*(I want to do this because there is a little bug with our BE that always returns `hasNextPage = true` and before implementing **Graphcache** I used `pageInfo.startCursor === pageInfo.endCursor` to check if it's the last page but I can't do that anymore with **Graphcache**)*